# change attributes of css class when javascript function runs

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

so I have this function below...

```
<script>          
$('.tile').on('click', function () {

    $(".tile").addClass("flipOutX");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".tile-group.six").load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");
    }, 2000);

});
</script>
```

I basically want to change the css attributes of tile-group.six to have a different margin.  Any ideas how I might go about this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change an element's CSS class with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".tile-group.six").css({margin:"0"});
```

This should be what you're after.

As *Phylogenesis* pointed out in his comment on the below answer, this method can be used to change multiple CSS values at once using a comma delimiter e.g.

```
$(".tile-group.six").css({margin:"0", padding:"0"});
```

Comment: this didnt seem to work -  $(".tile-group.main").css({ margin-left:"50px", width: "1080px"}).load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");

Comment: the function doesn't run at all

Comment: Okay, change `margin-left` to `marginLeft` and that *should* work

Comment: ok stupid me missing the uppercase on the L for left.... it works awesome, your a genius thanks ...  why the different name references then ? i am guessing javascript reads a - as something else

Comment: I think it is to do with the hyphen yes, another one off the top of my head is `backgroundColor`, which would be `background-color` or simply `background` in a style sheet :)

Answer (score 4):

you should take a look at the `.css()` function of jQuery
like

```
$(".tile-group.six").css('margin-left', '50px');
```

and so on

Comment: worked well thanks , the above answer used a slightly different syntax any ideas which one is better any why ?

Comment: Callum's answer allows you to set more than one CSS value at once: `$(selector).css({ cssKeyA: 'cssValueA', cssKeyB: 'cccValueB', ... });`, rather than `$(selector).css('cssKeyA', 'cssValueA').css('cssKeyB', 'cssValueB');`.

Comment: ah right , I think I will use that one in this instance thanks for your help buddy !

Comment: this didnt seem to work - $(".tile-group.main").css({ margin-left:"50px", width: "1080px"}).load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");